# How would I go about refreshing a specific thing on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to refresh my total bet number on a successful ajax call but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I'm sure it's not as complicated as I am making it. So I'm trying to get the new pointTotal from my JSON doc after the ajax call is sent.

Right now it gets all the updated information but I want the new point total for THAT specific game (there are multiple per page). This seems like something that should be easy for me but I've tried a lot of things and cant quite make it work. Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
getGames().done(function(results){
    $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
        $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

            var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
            var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;

            if(gamesHome == selectedValue || gamesAway == selectedValue){

                var gameId = game.id;
                var homeTeam = game.home_team.market;
                var awayTeam = game.away_team.market;
                var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                var homeId = game.home_team.id;
                var awayId = game.away_team.id;
                var network = game.broadcast_network;
                var homePoints = game.total_points_bet_on_hometeam;
                var awayPoints = game.total_points_bet_on_awayteam;
                var totalPoints = homePoints + awayPoints;
                var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';


            $('.wrapper').append('\
                <div id="'+ gameId +'" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                <div class="game-cards">\
                <div class="chart-container">\
                <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                </div>\
                <div class="right-info">\
                <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                <div class="total-points-live">\
                <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                <h5 class="total-points" id="point-total">'+ totalPoints +'</h5>\
                <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-away" data-away-id="'+ awayId +'" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-home" data-home-id="'+ homeId +'" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p class="bet-button" gameid="'+ gameId +'">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                </div>\
                </div>\
                </div>\
                ');


            $('.bet-input-away').on('input', function() {
               if($(this).val().length)
                  $('.bet-input-home').prop('disabled', true);
               else
                  $('.bet-input-home').prop('disabled', false);
            });
            $('.bet-input-home').on('input', function() {
               if($(this).val().length)
                  $('.bet-input-away').prop('disabled', true);
               else
                  $('.bet-input-away').prop('disabled', false);
            });


            var ctx = document.getElementById(homeTeam).getContext('2d');

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'doughnut',
              data: {
                labels: [homeTeam, awayTeam],
                datasets: [{
                  backgroundColor: [
                    hue,
                    hueTwo
                  ],
                  data: [homePoints, awayPoints]
                , borderWidth: 0
                }]
              },
              options: {
                    responsive: true
                ,   maintainAspectRatio: true
              }
            });

            }

        });

    });
});

$('.wrapper').on('click', '.bet-button', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
    var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
    var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();
    var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').data('away-id');
    var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').data('home-id');
    var pointTotals = $('#' + gameId + ' .total-points').val();
    console.log(pointTotals);
    var value = awayVal || homeVal;
    var id, value;


    if (awayVal) {
      id = awayId;
      value = awayVal;
    }
    if (homeVal) {
      id = homeId;
      value = homeVal;
    }

    if (!value) {
        alert('please enter a value!')
    } else {
        $.ajax({
          url: "---------" + userId + "/"+ gameId +"/"+ id +"/"+ value +"",
          type: "get",
        success: function(response) {

            // alert("YOU SUCCESSFULLY SUBMITTED A BET!")

            function update(){

                var currentSelection = $('#team-select').val();

                getGames().done(function(results){
                    $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
                        $.each(gameData, function(key, game){
                            var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                            var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;

                            if(gamesHome == currentSelection || gamesAway == currentSelection){
                                var gameId = game.id;
                                var homeTeam = game.home_team.market;
                                var awayTeam = game.away_team.market;
                                var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                                var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                                var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                                var homeId = game.home_team.id;
                                var awayId = game.away_team.id;
                                var network = game.broadcast_network;
                                var homePoints = game.total_points_bet_on_hometeam;
                                var awayPoints = game.total_points_bet_on_awayteam;
                                var totalPoints = homePoints + awayPoints;
                                var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                                var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';





                                // $('#point-total').append(homePoints + awayPoints);

                            }

                        });
                    });
                })
            }

            update();


            $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val(''); //This resets the value box
            $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val(''); //This resets the value box


        },
          error: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr)
          }
        });
```

Comment: Just a helpful tip: creating a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would render you an answer much quicker. Most people don't want to have to dig through your 100+ lines of code to explain an issue that can be recreated in 20. Try simplifying your code down as much as possible so we can get right to the crux of the issue. From there, you can plug a solution into your larger codebase

Comment: Side note that has nothing to do with your question: you shouldn't be registering event handlers inside of loops. They will register and fire as many times as you set them up. In this case `results.length * gameData.length` times.